# uninitialized constant ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After using the command `rails generate controller Say hello goodbye`, three files are generated:  `app/controllers/say_controller.rb`, and two `.erb.html` files
when I search for the URL: localhost:3000/say/hello  it returns:

`Uninitialized Constant ApplicationController` exception.

say_controller.rb

class:  Say_Controller < ApplicationController

```
 def: hello 
 end: 
 def: goodbye
 end
```

end:

as per several requests to reformat my question including correct nesting.  this is what the .rb file looks like.

Comment: Rails.root: /home/josh/Documents/rubys/work/demo
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/say_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

Routes

Comment: 1) What's the filename + filepath of your `application_controller.rb`? 2) Also, can you show your `application_controller.rb`? 3) Can you show your `say_controller.rb` specifically the very first line? (that shows what class is it extending).

Comment: say_controller:   class SayController < ApplicationController
  def hello
  end

  def goodbye
  end
end

Comment: the SayController.rb sits in the App/Controllers folder.

Comment: I think this is the path:  uninitialized constant ApplicationController

Rails.root: /home/josh/Documents/rubys/work/demo
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/say_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

Comment: your `SayController.rb` should be `say_controller.rb`. Similarly your `ApplicationController.rb` should be `application_controller.rb`

Comment: my question number 1) is asking about `application_controller.rb` and not `say_controller.rb`, so could you also provide that information? i'd like to check on some things thats why

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you deleted the `ApplicationController`, which lives in `application_controller.rb`. This is the base of any other controller that you generate, which is why `say_controller.rb` will begin like this:

```rb
class SayController < ApplicationController
```

When you deleted `say_controller.rb`, is it possible you deleted `application_controller.rb`? If so, and you use git to track files, you can restore the deleted file. Otherwise, you should probably generate a new Rails project.

Comment: Robin, thanks for your answer.  I also used the rails command destroy controller to undo the original commands, then after reentering the rails generate controller command again to create a new controller,  I still get the same error message.   its crazy because the controller is where its supposed to be along with the html files.  how do I use git to do what you said?

Comment: @jcane do you have a file `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`? That file is generated when you create a new Rails application. If you deleted it, you'll need to restore it. If you didn't use Git to track the files in the first place, you won't be able to restore the file. I recommend generating a new Rails project and copying `application_controller.rb` from there.

Comment: I have the say_controller.rb file.  once I take away the old controller with the destroy command, shouldn't I be able to generate an entire new controller with a new rails generate command?  additionally, I never saw a application_controller.rb  only the say_controller.rb.

Comment: remove  app/controllers/say_controller.rb
       route  get "say/goodbye"
       route  get "say/hello"
      invoke  erb
      remove    app/views/say
      remove    app/views/say/hello.html.erb
      remove    app/views/say/goodbye.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
      remove    test/controllers/say_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      remove    app/helpers/say_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit

Comment: If you're missing `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` then that is _definitely_ the issue. It is created by `rails new`. Generating a controller or destroying it does not affect this file, I just tested to be sure. Generate a new Rails project and you can copy `application_controller.rb` from it.

Comment: Robin, thank you!!  now working on creating the new project, and downloading all the gems etc etc.  an aggravating process :-)  but I'm learning!!  thanks again!!